# Change a target line of a file

Tags: file, bash, text, batch-file, command-line-interface

I'm running a process, which uses a set of parameters defined in a file *parameters.py*

Now, I'd like to swept the value of one of the parameters over certain range. Thus, I wrote a batch file to automatise the procedure.

**Problem**

My problem is that I need to modify the 20th line of the file parameter, from  `value = 200` to `value = $VAR`, where `$VAR` sets the new value of the parameter.

**Question**

Is there a bash command that allows to change a specific target line of the file?

Thank you and cheers.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *swept*.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for [tag:sed], which allows you to address a line in a stream (or file) and edit it, but I'm unclear as to why you are doing this in Bash rather than providing an argument to your Python script.

Comment: As @Johnsyweb alludes to perhaps you should state what you're trying to achieve, as to modify a Python script with ``sed`` or similar seems wrong, you should just pass in a CLI parameter or change it so that it gets the value from the environment. What process is using this ``parameters.py`` another Python script or shell.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) :

```
sed -i "20s/value = 200/value = $VAR/" file.txt
```

That will change `value = 200` to `value = $VAR` on line 20. `s///` is a skeleton for `sed` substitutions : `s/before/after/`

The `-i` switch edit the file in place

Comment: That should be `20s/`... instead of `4s/...`. (the number is the line to apply the search command)

Comment: @sputnick Thx for the quick response. Could you please explain me what does the value `4` do in the search? Because my file have multiple lines with the pattern `value = 200`... and I just need to change the 20th line.

Comment: Obligatory comment about `-i` flag being nonstandard: It doesn't exist in some `sed` implementations. On BSD its extension argument is required, and on GNU the argument is not.

Answer (score 2):

While it's certainly possible, I wouldn't recommend it. One day, someone will add a comment before this line or an empty line and your script will break.

Use `sed` instead:

```
sed -e 's/value = 200/value = $VAR/' < parameters.py
```

An even better solution would be to move everything in `parameters.py` into `parameterdefaults.py` like so:

parameterdefaults.py:

```
options = {
    "value": 200,
}
```

parameters.py:

```
import parameterdefaults

options = dict( **parameterdefaults.options ) # copy defaults

options['value'] = 10 # Override the few values you need to change
```

or even better:

codethatneedsparameters.py:

```
import parameterdefaults
import parameters

options = dict( **parameterdefaults.options ) # copy defaults
options.update( parameters.options ) # merge with changes
```

Now you can write:

parameters.py:

```
options = {
    "value": 10,
}
```

Comment: Take care, this solution replace all occurrences of `value = 200`, not only line 20

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way *(but not the best)* to do this instead of hacking the script is to change it from

```
value = 200
```

to

```
import os # somewhere at the top if need be.
value = int(os.environ.get('VAR', 200))
```

That way it can be modified from the calling process what ever that may be.